# where is the memory leak in the code below?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

Can you guys help me to identify where is the memory leak?

```
void foo(char *name){
    char * p = (char *)malloc(1024);
    char * buf = (char *)malloc(1024);
    sprintf(p, "User name: %s", name);
    printf("Format string is %s\n", p); 
    buf = p;
    free(p);
    free(buf);
}
```

Comment: You lose a pointer to the second `malloc`ed block by overwriting `buf` and then try to free the first `malloc`ed block twice

Comment: This doesn't just leak memory; it also invokes *undefined behavior* by freeing the same pointer value (`p`) twice.

Comment: Tip: Don't use useless casts. Neither of those `(char *)` are needed.

Answer (score 3):

1. You allocate a memory block we'll call BLOCK1. `p` initially points to BLOCK1.
2. You allocate a memory block we'll call BLOCK2. `buf` initially points to BLOCK2.
3. `buf` is changed to point to BLOCK1 (`buf = p;`). Nothing points to BLOCK2 now. Memory leak.
4. You free BLOCK1 (`free(p)`), but you never free BLOCK2.

Also, you invoke *undefined behaviour* by attempting to free a block that has already been freed (`free(buf)`).

If you are trying to copy the string, `strncpy` or `strcpy` should be used in lieu of `buf = p;`.

If you are trying to copy the pointer, only allocate one block (using `char *buf = p;` in lieu of `char *buf = malloc(...); buf = p;`).

Answer (score 0):

this is the memory leak:

```
buf = p;
```

because it overlays one of the pointers to allocated memory.

However, due to the above statement, this statement:

```
free(buf);
```

will cause a program crash because the memory pointed to be `buf`  has already been passed to `free()`

so, two bad things in the posted code.

To fix it all, remove this statement:

```
buf = p;
```